# Join string with specific word for RowFilter

Tags: vb.net

I have rowfilter which i use to filter my datasource. I have couple controls which user can pick up checking specific checkboxes either to be used for Rowilter or not. Below code.

```
    Dim ds = CType(dgvAbmessungen.PrimaryGrid.DataSource, DataSet)
    Dim dtMain As DataTable = ds.Tables(0)

    Dim filterStr As String = String.Empty

    Dim byNummer As String = " [Nummer] like '" & txtFilterByNummer.Text.Trim() & "%'"
    Dim byUser As String = " [User] = '" + cbUser.Text
    Dim byCreateDateFrom As String = " [CreateDate] >= '" + CType(Convert.ToDateTime(calFrom.Value.Date), String)
    Dim byCreateDateTo As String = "' ([CreateDate] < '" + CType(Convert.ToDateTime(calTo.Value.Date), String)


    'select case checboxes and construct final rowfilter's string

 dtMain.DefaultView.RowFilter = filterStr
```

Checboxes for diffrent controls to be checked:

```
for Nummer there is checkboxNummer
for User there is checkboxUser
for CreateDateFrom there is checkboxCreateDateFrom 
for CreateDateTo there is checkboxCreateDateTo
```

Target is user checks one or more checboxes and filter should be constructed (string). Problem is i have no idea how to also concat "And" keywords between strings if user check more than one diffrent checboxes.

Currently i try to do it using select case. What could be the most efficient way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

I would use LINQ:

```
Dim data = dtMain.AsEnumerable()
If checkboxNummer.Checked Then
    data = data.Where(Function(row) row.Field(Of String)("Nummer").Contains(txtFilterByNummer.Text.Trim()))
End If
If checkboxUser.Checked Then
    data = data.Where(Function(row) row.Field(Of String)("User") = cbUser.Text.Trim())
End If
If CreateDateFrom.Checked Then
    data = data.Where(Function(row) row.Field(Of Date)("CreateDate") >= calFrom.Value.Date)
End If
If CreateDateTo.Checked Then
    data = data.Where(Function(row) row.Field(Of Date)("CreateDate") < calTo.Value.Date)
End If
```

If you need the result as `DataRow()` use `data.ToArray()`. If you need a `DataTable` use:

```
If data.Any() Then dtMain = data.CopyToDataTable()
```

Comment: if possible to not by linq would be great.

Comment: @Dino: you have asked for the _most efficient way_. This is efficient because of LINQ's deferred execution. There are multiple queries that are merged to one and which gets executed at `data.ToArray()`

Comment: keep in mind i have to put the entire string into: dtMain.DefaultView.RowFilter = "my final string of filter". How to do so using your example?

Comment: @Dino: you don't need the old and limited `RowFilter` syntax anymore. I don't fiddle around with strings but with strongly typed .NET methods. If `Nummer` is actually an `Integer` you have to use `Field(Of Int32)` and you have to cast txtFilterByNummer.Text to integer.

Comment: ok so how to change my dtMain.DefaultView.RowFilter = "filterStr" my datagridview to show result? Keep in mind as RowFilter i do not want to change oryginal datasource.

Comment: @Dino: as mentioned in my answer, use `data.ToArray` if you want a `DataRow()`. What you want to do with the filtered result? You can even create a new DataTable with the filtered result, therefore use `data.CopyToDataTable()`. But note that this raises an exception if there was not at least one row, so you have to use `If data.Any() Then dtMain=data.CopyToDataTable()`.

Comment: after RowFilter is done my datagridview should be filtered based on that filter Till now i was doing that using mentioned RowFilter method but you proposed different approach so i am asking. Keep in mind i do not want to change oryginal datasource as RowFilter for example doing (not touching oryginal datasource but just uses its data)

Comment: @Dino: you use a `BindingSource`? Just assign `data` or `data.ToArray` as datasource and you are finished

Comment: @Time Schmelter: I just use mydatagrid.Datassource = and here getting from sql query directly without binding source.  If data.Any() Then dtMain = data or data.ToArray - i cannot do this statment (error)
P.S Note that for example for Nummer it should be Like instead of equal...

Comment: `Then dtMain = data.CopyToDataTable()`... i have edited my answer to show it and also to show you the .NET `Like` which is `String.Contains` ;-)

Comment: @TimSchelter how to refresh then datagridview because rowfilter is doing that automaticly. Keep in mind in the datasouce besides dtMain (Tables(0)) there is also another one dtCombinations (Tables(1)) which are also refrenced between by some fields in this datasource. Does this data.CopyToDataTable() keeps that references or?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149001/discussion-between-tim-schmelter-and-dino).